# How to get all models,controller,action and method names in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, action, actioncontroller

In runtime we can get the current controller and current action names by controller_name and action_name methods like wise,

I want to get all the remaining controllers and action names and models too if possible..

Any rails method available to get all the controller names and the action names in application controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
@table_names =  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
    @model_names = Array.new
    @model_names.each do |table_to_model|
      @model_names = @model_names.insert(@model_names.length,table_to_model.camelize.singularize) unless table_to_model.blank?
    end
```

This is how you get all Model name

Comment: Thanks alot ..By this way is it possible to get controller names and action and method names ...

Thanks in Advance..

Regards,
Ramanaa Selvaa

Comment: There's a typo in sachin7036's answer. The 3rd line should read "@table_names.each do |table_to_model|". You can get the controller name for a model by doing something like...
kontroller = eval("#{model_name.camelcase<<'Controller'}") You can get the action names (in 2.3.8 or lower) by doing something like...
actions = kontroller.action_methods